# Graph Giant Connected Component

Tags: python, networking, graph, connected-components

i have a matrix of the form

```
a b 8.0
a d 0.1
......
```

where 1st column is Node A,2nd Node B and 3rd correlation coefficient
i have to make a program that finds a threshold thus the connected network has a Giant Connected Component consist of 50-60% of total Network nodes.
I wrote a program that using a binary search for the threshold like

```
if Giant Connected Component > 60% new threshold=oldthreshold + oldthreshold/2
if Giant Connected Component < 50% new threshold=oldthreshold - oldthreshold/2
```

The problem is that algorithm is also searching for thresholds > 1 and/or <0 .How i can handle this.Or is there any better idea how to calculate it?

Comment: You could find the minimum and maximum values in the table and use those as the starting range for binary search.

Comment: threshold must be  1>rc>0

Comment: Ah, I see.  Your problem is that you are not correctly implementing binary search.  I'll answer in more detail in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you describe is not binary search.

To correctly implement binary search, keep track of two values, `min_threshold` and `max_threshold`.  Initially set these to the minimum and maximum possible threshold values.  Then at each step:

```
threshold = (min_threshold + max_threshold)/2
if GCC(threshold) > 60%:  # threshold is too low, update minimum
    min_threshold = threshold
else if GCC(threshold) < 50%:  # threshold is too high, update maximum
    max_threshold = threshold
```

Comment: thnx i will try it now and write how it works at couple of hours .It is a 45Gb .dat file

Comment: `if GCC(threshold) > 60%:` is not valid python code BTW.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, this is pseudocode similar to what the OP used in his question.